# Show All event as AllDay in fullcalendar also if its false.

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

I have a problem with AllDay events, in a fullcalendar, if i set allday to false then its still showed as allday, can someone see why !?
I have added allday, so i dont know if its the right name i use, but the calendar works fine, its just showing all events as AllDays.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="fullcalendarjson" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO

Public Class fullcalendarjson : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    context.Response.Expires = -1
    Dim tasksList As IList(Of CalendarDTO) = New List(Of CalendarDTO)()

    tasksList.Add(New CalendarDTO() With { _
        .id = 1, _
        .title = "Google search", _
        .start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now), _
        .[end] = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)), _
        .url = "www.google.com", _
        .allday = False _
    })
    tasksList.Add(New CalendarDTO() With { _
        .id = 1, _
        .title = "Bing search", _
        .start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)), _
        .[end] = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)), _
        .url = "www.bing.com", _
        .allday = False _
    })
    tasksList.Add(New CalendarDTO() With { _
        .id = 1, _
        .title = "AllDay search", _
        .start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)), _
        .[end] = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)), _
        .url = "www.bing.com", _
        .allday = True _
    })
    Dim oSerializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim sJSON As String = oSerializer.Serialize(tasksList)
    context.Response.Write(sJSON)
End Sub

Private Function ToUnixTimespan([date] As DateTime) As Long
    Dim tspan As TimeSpan = [date].ToUniversalTime().Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

    Return CLng(Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds))
End Function

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
Public Class CalendarDTO
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As Integer
    Public Property title() As String
        Get
            Return m_title
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_title = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_title As String
    Public Property start() As Long
        Get
            Return m_start
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            m_start = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_start As Long
    Public Property [end]() As Long
        Get
            Return m_end
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            m_end = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_end As Long
    Public Property url() As String
        Get
            Return m_url
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_url = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_url As String
    Public Property allday() As String
        Get
            Return m_allday
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_allday = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_allday As String
End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allday should be allDay - the d is caps. By default allDay is true - but this default behavior can be controlled using the `allDayDefault` option - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/

Comment: hi Ganeshk
I have tryed this.
Im main Script added allDayDefualt: false,
In the Handler i have changes all m_allday and allday() to allDay, but its still showing the events as all day, and the allDay is false !?

Comment: I fix it AllDay is not a string its a Boolean...
But i dont understand that in day and week view i get the time as 24H 20:00 to 22:00 but in/on month view its showing "8p Eventname" Whay that !??